# Memory required to store 1000 telephone numbers

Tags: algorithm, bit

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685649/most-efficient-way-to-store-thousand-telephone-numbers) question,

but didn't understand some part of the aix's answer that 
how it requires only 17 bits to store 5 digits of the telephone numbers and how the total becomes 2128 bytes to store 1000 numbers.

please help me with this silly doubt.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First 5 digits should be stored once, so since 5 digits means a number in 0-99999 in decimal base you need to store at least this in binary.

Now the first binary value which allows you to fit 99999 numbers is 131072, which is 2^17. So 17 bits go for the common prefix.

Now you need to store 1000 5 digits numbers for the lowest part of every single number. Same approach as before. **17 bits per number = 17000 bits.**

`Total: 17000 + 17 = 17017 bits`.

Every byte has 8 bits, so

`17017/8 = 2127.125`.

You need at least **2128 bytes**.

Comment: Thanks for this lucid explanation,but still have a doubt.Shouldn't it be 17-1=16 because on ceiling of 99999 i.e (131072),number of bits required to store number increases by one.So, if 131072 requires 17 bits, numbers in the range (65536 - 131071) should require 16 bits.So, it should be 16. Am i missing something ?

Comment: @abhi120 Actually, `2^k` requires `k+1` bits, so 131072 requires 18 bits (for `2^0` through `2^17`) and numbers 65536 through 131071 require 17 bits.

Comment: @abhi120: yes, I meant that you need the range 0-131071 to store a number in 0-99999. These are 131072 possible numbers so 2^17.

Comment: @Jack can you please help me understanding how will you store these last 5 digits in 17 bits and do a binary search to find a number in java. I tried whole night understanding but with no result.

Answer (score 2):

10<sup>5</sup> = 100000.  ceil(log<sub>2</sub>(100000)) = 17.

Comment: I thought your answer needed a bit of explanation... shouldn't have downvoted it though, sorry.