# new to programming - it takes 17 bits to store 5 digits - how?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179516/memory-required-to-store-1000-telephone-numbers) which stated it takes 17 bits to store 5 digits, how is that possible? Here is what I understand:

I used the [following calculator](http://acc6.its.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~gurwitz/core5/nav2tool.html) and entered the number 99999.

I got this huge number:

`11000000111001110000110100111111100001101001111111000011010011111`

From what I understand, each `0` and `1` represents one bit. As you can see, there are more than 17 bits!

Am I understanding this wrong?

Also, it was also stated:

> "Now the first binary value which allows you to fit 99999 numbers is 131072,"

Huh? I thought binary values are ONLY 0 and 1? What am I missing here?

Comment: When I'm trying the calculator you linked to, I get 99999 -> 11000011010011111 which is 17 bits indeed...

Comment: I am getting `11000011010011111`

Comment: The last part is just the smallest power of two. 131072 is 2¹⁷. Since each bit holds two values, that translates to 17 bits.

Comment: The issue is the tool is pretty bad. If you hit `convert` multiple times, it just appends to the end of the last conversion.

Comment: OP it seems that 'calculator' has threw you a curve ball.

Comment: FWIW, Windows has a perfectly good calculator that will translate between decimal, binary, hex, and octal.

Comment: @resueman Yep, I've inspected the JavaScript, it's on the rank of "my first program". Specifically, it has this: `document.forms[0].elements[1].value+=(answer[i]);` and this is never preceded by a `document.forms[0].elements[1].value = "";`

Comment: "Now the first binary value which allows you to fit 99999 numbers is 131072,"  The person who said that quite likely does not have a deep understanding of the subject.  It would make more sense if (s)he had said, the first _power of two_ greater than 99999 is 2^17 (131072).  All modern computers store integer values in binary place-value representation.  "Bit" is short for "Binary digIT,"  and each bit in a binary number represents a different power of two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

99 999 in binary is 11000011010011111, exactly as your calculator says. I don't know what you entered but clearly you made a typo somewhere.

17 bits can store a number up to 2^17, hence = 131072, while 16 bits can only store up to 
2^16 = 65536.

So you do need at least 17 bits to store 99 999, not any more, not any less.

Comment: If you encode 1 to mean 99_999, then you only need one bit. The point is that you need 17 bits to store 100_000 *distinct values*.

Comment: Shouldn't this be 131071 and 65535 if we talk about unsigned numbers (zero including)?

Answer (score 2):

2^16 = 65,536, so to capture every 5 digit number, you'd need 2^17 = 17 bits.

The part about "first binary value ..." makes no sense to me

Comment: probably means that before 2^17 you can't store ALL 5 digit decimal values. idk

Comment: 131072 is 2^17, the smallest power of two greater than 99999.

Answer (score 1):

Well, 16 bits can store a number as high as `2^16 - 1 = 65535`. That's assuming unsigned numbers (non-negative), which means it is not enough to represent of 5 digits decimal numbers.

With 17 bits you can get represent unsigned numbers as high as `2^17 -1 = 131071`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is finding your way through the imprecise language typically used between persons equally experienced within a domain. The number 131072 is 2<sup>17</sup>, and that is the smallest power of two which exceeds five digits in decimal notation. In other words, to store any 5 decimal digits, you need those 17 bits because that's the smallest number of bits which covers the range 0-99999.

In the quote you present the author assumes familiarity with the number 131072, the fact that it is a power of two, therefore a round number in binary notation, and the fact that, for any `n`, there are exactly 2<sup>n</sup> distinct `n`-digit binary numbers.

Comment: I still dont understand what 131072 represents.. I know how they derived it.. but what does that number tell us ?

Comment: Try to phrase your comment to focus on one aspect which is bothering you. I don't know how to answer that.

Comment: @shmedfred, in order to understand what 131072 represents, you need to understand place-value number systems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation), and especially, the base-2 (a.k.a., "binary") place-value system.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using an online calculator, I would use Java and [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) with something like -

```
int val = 99999;
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(val);
System.out.printf("%d is binary %s and %d binary digits long", val,
        binaryString, binaryString.length());
```

And the output is

```
99999 is binary 11000011010011111 and 17 binary digits long
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possibilities for storing a 5 digit decimal number:

```
00000
11111
22222
33333
44444
55555
66666
77777
88888
99999
```

For each digit, you have 10 (i.e. "base 10") possible values, and with 5 digits you have 10*10*10*10*10 = 10^5 = 100000 (0 is counted) possible values.

For a 17 digit binary number:

```
00000000000000000
11111111111111111
```

Using the same logic, you have 2*2*...*2 = 2^17 = 131072 possible values ranging from 0 to 131071.  As to why you need 17 bits? Well, 2^16 = 65536, which can't hold 99999.